# Singular elliptic PDE: $-h\,\Delta u +\langle \nabla h,\nabla u\rangle =h$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $0\in U$. Fix $h\in L^2(U)\cap C^\infty(U)$ with $h(0)=0$. Is there some $C^1$-function $u\neq 0$ in such that $u$ is solution of 
$$-h\,\Delta u +\langle \nabla h,\nabla u\rangle =h?$$

The main point in this equation is the fact that $h(0)=0$ it turns hard apply the techniques of elliptic equations. I have thought about solve assuming that $h$ vanishes only on $0$ then use a exhaustion by compact to build solutions using the classical elliptic pde theory. I am not an expert in pde's, I haven't can showed that the limit has sufficiently regularity.

I have looked at Google about "Singular Elliptic PDE's" but I didn't find references that cover this case. I will be very grateful if you could give some light over the theory of the Singular Elliptic PDE's.
I mean by Singular Elliptic PDE's some operator that is elliptic except for a point.

Comment: how about $u(x)=0$?

Comment: I will need the flow of $\nabla u$, I forget to input the hypothesis that $u\neq =0 $.

Comment: if you divide the equation by $h$ then the equation is of the form $ -\Delta u + \nabla \gamma \cdot \nabla u =1$ and this equation is of variational form and this may help one try some stuff.   For another (maybe better) approach lets assume $h(x)=|x|^t$ where $t>0$.    So the equation then becomes $ -\Delta u + t \frac{x}{|x|^2} \nabla u=1$.    Try looking for a solution on the puntured ball $B_1 \backslash \{0\}$ using spherical harmonics:  $ u(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(r) \phi_k(\theta)$ where $ \phi_k$ are the eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator on $S^{N-1}$.

Comment: @Math604 Thanks for your comment. I have a question, how to pass from the solution for the punctured ball $B_{1}\setminus \{0\}$ to a solution on ball $B_{1}$?

Comment: @melomm : . . . and I've further corrected it further by putting a small space between $h$ and $\Delta u$, just as one does between $f(x)$ and $dx$, getting $f(x)\,dx$ rather than $f(x)dx$ (actually many mathematicians who otherwise can spell miss that one), or between $\partial x$ and $\partial y$ in the denominator of a mixed partial derivative.

Comment: @melomm.   To pass to the limit on the full ball it should be sufficeint that your solution on the puntured ball grows slower than the fundamental solution near the origin... so it will depend on $t$...